# is optative sentence is a different types of sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, types-of-sentences

there are four types of sentence according purpose.
1 declarative 2.interrogative 3. imperative 4.exclamative

is optative sentence the part of these types or itself a sentence type?
please guide

Comment: The clause types you list are the major ones. Optative is a minor clause type which expresses wishes, for example "Long live the King" and "May all your troubles be quickly resolved". Note that the first one is a subjunctive, the other a hybrid.

Comment: I'd say "optative" is really just a subtype within "imperative" that includes the speaker as well as the addressee (so imperative *[You] Have a rest* becomes ***Let's** have a rest*).

Comment: The imperative is characteristically used to express a directive, while optatives express wishes. Some optatives are subjunctives, as in the example I gave earlier, as well as others like "So be it" / "God help you if you're late again". In, for example, "Long may he reign over us" there is some semantic resemblance between this specialised use of "may" and that of "let" in open _let_ imperatives, but syntactically the NP following "may" is clearly the subject. Finally, there are the hybrids like the archaic "Would that he were still alive", for example.